# How to display the table without knowing the table name?

Tags: php, mysql

This is my code

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost:3307";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "female"; //database 

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname); //open ng connection 
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 


$username = $_POST['username']; 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $username";
$result = $conn->query($sql); 
echo "<div class='con'>";
echo "Men";
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {


        echo "<table id='contestant'>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$row[0]."</td>"; 
        echo "<td>".$row[6]."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</table>";
        echo "</div>";
                 }

} else 
{
    echo "<div class='con'>";
     echo "<ul id='contestant'>0 Contestant</ul>";
     echo "</div>";

}

?>
```

The $_POST['username'] is the input name where the user input their username because it serves as the table name.Also, to determine what table should be display. My problem is my code doesn't work that's why I'm asking that is it possible to display the table without knowing the table name.

Comment: I would strongly suggest you read about Database normalization: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: @callme123 Why your code is not working? Can you also add the error you are getting?

Comment: I must say that if you're creating a table per user your's setting yourself up for a real hot hot smoldering mess.

Comment: I can't agree with icecub and Augwa more. **DO NOT** go down this road. Once you have >1000 users your database will become utterly unmaintainable. Your administration tools will crash when you open them. Making even tiny schema changes will turn into a world of hurt so bad you'll wish you'd never done this in the first place.

Comment: Whatever you do, **DO NOT** put raw `$_POST` data in your query. You need to verify that's a valid table name and not some hostile SQL.